# Crashing while assigning nil to UIViewController after removing view and popping

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a sequence in which I need to pop a `UIViewcontroller` from outside the class. From the server I will get an log out event, and I need to pop the view controller if it is open. So I have done this to find the top view controller and pop it:

```
UIViewController *top_view_ctrlr = [self.navigationController topViewController];
if (top_view_ctrlr.view != nil) {
    [top_view_ctrlr.view removeFromSuperview];
}

// Popping only the top view controller.
[top_view_ctrlr.navigationController popToViewController:dash animated:NO];
```

Then I am setting `nil` for all the view controllers created, e.g.:

```
if (history != nil) {
    history = nil; // Here history is an view controller. Because it is not on top, I am setting only nil here to release all its memory. 
}
```

As I am using ARC, I guess I don't need to worry much about memory release inside history. However, it's crashing with:

> `[history_class tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`: message sent to deallocated instance.

What could be the problem? Why it is crashing when I set the object to `nil`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you remove the `topViewController`'s view from its superview? You should never need to do that in a navigation controller, `popToViewController:` does that automatically, and removing a view "behind the navigation controller's back" is probably causing the crash.

Comment: Thanx for your answer.. Actually I have done like that to avoid adding a method in all class to do the pop operation. So assigning object to nil is not a problem then?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you plan to achieve, but I fear you lack some fundamental understanding of how to use UIViewControllers and UINavigationControllers, that's why I recommend reading this first:

[View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)

I'm sure it will help you with your current problem and in the future.